# Не работает onchange на добавленный input

Tags: html, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить данную проблему?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").append('<input type="text">');
});
$("input").on("change", function() {
  console.log("ok");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, возможно, вам нужно событие `input`, а не `change` (предположение)

Во-вторых, надо использовать **[делегирование событий](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On#.D0.9F.D1.80.D1.8F.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B8_.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.BA.D0.B0_.28.D0.BF.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.80_selector.29)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").append('<input type="text">');
});
$(document).on("input", "input", function() {
  console.log("ok");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: @Vector ну значит будет не `on('input',...)`, а `.on('blur', ...`

Answer (score 0):

Создайте необходимый элемент: `$input = $('<input type="text" />');`. После этого Вы можете добавлять обработчики непосредственно к созданному элементу: `$input.on('event'...`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $input = $('<input type="text">');
  $input.change(function() {
    console.log('on element: %о', this.value);
  });
  $("div").append($input);
})
.on('change', 'input', function(e) {
    console.log('on document: %o', e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Поиграться можно [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/XelaNimed/oq0cnu9L/), т.к. что-то внутренняя песочница как-то коряво работает.